# Whitespaces and Regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to determine if a string contains Invalid chars. The criteria is that it should only have `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `[0-9]` and `[/,.-\]` characters and anything else is *invalid*. Also, *chars followed by space followed by / followed by space followed by chars* is *valid*. The regex I have below takes care of the first criteria but I am struggling with the second. I have tried many combinations, something like these, but no success.

```
public bool ContainsInvalidChars(string s)
{
    return new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9/,.-][@"\s/\s"]).IsMatch(s);
}

Examples of input strings:

below is Valid
CSU,USD,6230.67,705RA0 / 2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM

below is invalid
CSU,USD,6230.67,705RA0 /2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM

below is invalid
CSU, USD,6230.67,705RA0 / 2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your method does not return any value. You should use `return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"pattern_here");`.

Comment: Try `return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(?!\s/\s)(?<!\s/(?=\s))[^a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]");`

Comment: looks like X/Y for me. Imo use a well build CSV parser and trim the field. A space in front of a value should not be enough to make a line invalid.

Comment: Have you tried my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two types of valid chunks:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]
\s/\s
```

let's make an arbitrary combination of them (note *anchors* `^` and `$` - we want *entire* string match)

```
^(?:(?:\s/\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]*)*$
```

Finally, *invalid* means *not matched*:

**Code:**

```
 public static bool ContainsInvalidChars(string s) =>
   !Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(?:(?:\s/\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]*)*$");
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  @"CSU,USD,6230.67,705RA0 / 2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM",
  @"CSU,USD,6230.67,705RA0 /2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM",
  @"CSU, USD,6230.67,705RA0 / 2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM",
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,-60} :: {(ContainsInvalidChars(test) ? "Invalid" : "Valid")}"));   

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
CSU,USD,6230.67,705RA0 / 2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM        :: Valid
CSU,USD,6230.67,705RA0 /2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM         :: Invalid
CSU, USD,6230.67,705RA0 / 2YKMP,5/11/2020,5/11/2020,VM       :: Invalid
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Learned something new about Regex from your responses.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the character class and repeat 0+ times in a group starting with space `/` space and again the character class.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]+(?: / [a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z0-9%2f%2c.-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a+%2f+%5ba-zA-Z0-9%2f%2c.-%5d%2b%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=below+is+Valid%0d%0aCSU%2cUSD%2c6230.67%2c705RA0+%2f+2YKMP%2c5%2f11%2f2020%2c5%2f11%2f2020%2cVM%0d%0a%0d%0abelow+is+invalid%0d%0aCSU%2cUSD%2c6230.67%2c705RA0+%2f2YKMP%2c5%2f11%2f2020%2c5%2f11%2f2020%2cVM%0d%0a%0d%0abelow+is+invalid%0d%0aCSU%2c+USD%2c6230.67%2c705RA0+%2f+2YKMP%2c5%2f11%2f2020%2c5%2f11%2f2020%2cVM&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/qxAH4R)

The code could look like

```
public bool ContainsInvalidChars(string s)
{
    return new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]+(?: / [a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]+)*$").IsMatch(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
public bool ContainsInvalidChars(string s)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(?!\s/\s)(?<!\s/(?=\s))[^a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]");
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F!%5Cs%2F%5Cs%29%28%3F%3C!%5Cs%2F%28%3F%3D%5Cs%29%29%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%2F%2C.-%5D&i=CSU%2C%20USD%2C6230.67%2C705RA0%20%2F2YKMP%2C5%2F11%2F2020%2C5%2F11%2F2020%2CVM)

**Regex details**

- `(?!\s/\s)` - a location not immediately followed with whitespace + `/` + whitespace
- `(?<!\s/(?=\s))` - a location not immediately preceded with whitespace + `/` and then followed with whitespace
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]` - any char but an ASCII letter, digit, `/`, `,`, `.` or `-`.

The two lookarounds just exclude matching whitespaces (that are otherwise matched with `[^a-zA-Z0-9/,.-]`) that are in a WHITESPACE + `/` + WHITESPACE chunk.